# Dired: hide "Omitted N lines" message

Tags: dired

I have these settings for dired

```
(setq-default dired-omit-files-p t)
(setq dired-omit-files (concat dired-omit-files "\\|^\\..+$"))
```

I was wondering if it is possible to hide/disable the message `Omitted N lines.`

Whenever I have a Dired buffer opened, the message appears repeatedly. For example: it appears when I am trying to switch to another
buffer and when I use `smex`.

It is just annoying having the minibuffer cluttered with that message when I am
trying to do something not strictly related to Dired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the omit messages by setting `dired-omit-verbose` variable to `nil`.

```el
(defcustom dired-omit-verbose t
  "When non-nil, show messages when omitting files.
When nil, don't show messages."
  :version "24.1"
  :type 'boolean
  :group 'dired-x)
```

*- From `dired-x.el`*

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @kaushalmodi has said, you should not need to work around this annoyance at all.

**You should not see that message displayed more than once.** And certainly not when you are "*trying to do something not strictly related to Dired.*"

Does that happen also when you start Emacs without your init file (i.e., `emacs -Q`)?

If not, then recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit code. You can comment out a region of your init file using `M-x comment-region` (with `C-u` it uncomments). Do that to 1/2 of the file, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16, etc. until you've narrowed it down to the culprit. This is quicker than it sounds to do - it's a binary search.